# Alexa node.js sdk error requestHandler.canHandle is not a function

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I am getting this error using Alexa sdk for node.js. Any ideas?

```
this.skill = Alexa.SkillBuilders.custom()
            .addRequestHandlers(
                intendsArray
            ).create();

TypeError: requestHandler.canHandle is not a function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue was caused by that I forgot to add three dots ... before an array in `addRequestHandlers()` function.

```
this.skill = Alexa.SkillBuilders.custom()
            .addRequestHandlers(
                ...intendsArray
            ).create();
```